# Unable to find dialect at @journeyapps/sqlcipher

Tags: electron, sqlcipher

I’m trying to connect to already encypted local Sqlite3 DB with @journeyapps/sqlcipher in an Electron App. i used db browser to encrypt the db with password. i got following error when try to connect to database.

Uncaught Error: Unable to find dialect at @journeyapps/sqlcipher
at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (B:\rtapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:53)
at new ConnectionManager (B:\rtapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:18)
at new SqliteDialect (B:\rtapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\index.js:13)
at new Sequelize (B:\rtapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:194)
at tests.html:35

OS: Windows 10
Node: 20.11.1
Electron: 6.1.7
Sequelize: 6.37.1
@journeyapps/sqlcipher: 5.3.1

Package json:

```
 `"name": "rt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "rt tool application",
  "productName": "rt tool",
  "main": "index.js",
  "icon": "./Images/logo1.ico",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": " electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "build": "electron-packager . all"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "electron-winstaller": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@journeyapps/sqlcipher": "^5.3.1",
    "@stdlib/math": "0.0.11",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "datalize": "^0.3.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "electron-context-menu": "^2.3.0",
    "electron-css": "^0.14.4",
    "electron-dl": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery.js": "0.0.2-security",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.3.1",
    "jspdf-html2canvas": "^1.1.0",
    "jszip": "^3.7.1",
    "math.js": "^1.1.45",
    "mathjs": "^6.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mssql": "^5.1.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.11.0",
    "promise": "^8.1.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "round-to": "^5.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "sql.js": "^1.0.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "ted": "^0.1.1",
    "tedious": "^6.3.0",
    "xlsx-populate": "^1.21.0"
  }
}`

code:

`const db_user = new Sequelize("RT","","1234",
{
dialect: "sqlite",
dialectModulePath: '@journeyapps/sqlcipher',
storage: path.join(__dirname,'RT.db'),       
       }
    );
// SQLCipher config
db_user.query("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 4");
db_user.query("PRAGMA key = '1234'");

async function connectdb(){
try {
await db_user.authenticate();
return console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
return console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
}`
```